# Добавление элемента в начало списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Есть список со списками, первый список имеет максимальный размер:

```
inp = [
    ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1', 'E1']
    ['C2', 'D2', 'E2']
    ['D3', 'E3']
    ['A4', 'B4', 'C4', 'D4', 'E4']
    ['C5', 'D5', 'E5']
    ['D6', 'E6']
    ['C7', 'D7', 'E7']
]
```

Надо что бы предыдущий список дополнял своими знач текущий список
В результате должен получиться вот такой список списков

```
out = [
    ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1', 'E1']
    ['A1', 'B1', 'C2', 'D2', 'E2']
    ['A1', 'B1', 'C2', 'D3', 'E3']
    ['A4', 'B4', 'C4', 'D4', 'E4']
    ['A4', 'B4', 'C5', 'D5', 'E5']
    ['A4', 'B4', 'C5', 'D6', 'E6']
    ['A4', 'B4', 'C7', 'D7', 'E7']
]
```

Подскажите пжлст, я не понимаю как это сделать

Comment: а если первый элемент меньше второго - первый тоже надо дополнить? но чем - пустыми значениями?

Comment: забыл, первый элемент всегда максимальный

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import itertools

def complement(x, y):
    return x[:-len(y)] + y or x

inp = [
    ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1', 'E1'],
    ['C2', 'D2', 'E2'],
    ['D3', 'E3'],
    ['A4', 'B4', 'C4', 'D4', 'E4'],
    ['C5', 'D5', 'E5'],
    ['D6', 'E6'],
    ['C7', 'D7', 'E7'],
]

out = list(itertools.accumulate(inp, complement))
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 2):

**окончательный код:**

```
inp = [
    ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1', 'E1'],
    ['C2', 'D2', 'E2'],
    ['D3', 'E3'],
    ['A4', 'B4', 'C4', 'D4', 'E4'],
    ['C5', 'D5', 'E5'],
    ['D6', 'E6'],
    ['C7', 'D7', 'E7']
]

# определить максимальный размер строк
max_len = len(max(inp, key=len))

# сформировать хранилище добавочных элементов
storage = [''] * max_len

# добавить новые элементы
for obj in inp:
    # вычислить кол-во элементов, которые требуется добавить
    new_len = max_len - len(obj)

    # добавить недостающие элементы
    obj[:] = storage[:new_len] + obj

    # обновить хранилище
    storage = obj

print(*inp, sep="\n")
```

первый вариант

```
inp = [
    ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1', 'E1'],
    ['C2', 'D2', 'E2'],
    ['D3', 'E3'],
    ['A4', 'B4', 'C4', 'D4', 'E4'],
    ['C5', 'D5', 'E5'],
    ['D6', 'E6'],
    ['C7', 'D7', 'E7']
]

# определить максимальный размер строк
max_len = len(max(inp, key=len))

# сформировать хранилище добавочных элементов
storage = [''] * max_len

# добавить новые элементы
for obj in inp:
    # вычислить кол-во элементов, которые требуется добавить
    new_len = max_len - len(obj)

    # добавить недостающие элементы
    for index in range(new_len):
        obj.insert(0, storage[new_len - index - 1])

    # обновить хранилище
    storage = obj

print(*inp, sep="\n")
```

чуть другой подход (не знаю какой лучше, но второй чуть короче и без явного цикла):

```
# добавить новые элементы
for index, obj in enumerate(inp):
    # вычислить кол-во элементов, которые требуется добавить
    new_len = max_len - len(obj)

    # добавить недостающие элементы
    inp[index] = storage[:new_len] + obj

    # обновить хранилище
    storage = inp[index]
```

Comment: Ты воспользовался тем, что в списках всегда полный хвост? Не заметил этого)

Comment: @vp_arth, т.е. полный хвост?

Comment: во входном списке нет ничего вроде `['A3', 'C3']`

Comment: Для понимания, о чём я(см. any): [fiddle](https://www.online-python.com/yUd64bkAx0)

Answer (score 2):

```
inp = [
    ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1', 'E1'],
    ['C2', 'D2', 'E2'],
    ['D3', 'E3'],
    ['A4', 'B4', 'C4', 'D4', 'E4'],
    ['C5', 'D5', 'E5'],
    ['D6', 'E6'],
    ['C7', 'D7', 'E7'],
]

pattern = inp[0]
for i, l in enumerate(inp[1:]):
    replacement = []
    for j, e in enumerate(pattern): 
        expected = f'{e[0]}{i+2}'
        replacement.append(expected if expected in l else e)
    l[:] = replacement
    pattern = l

for l in inp:
    print(l)
```

Comment: "капец ты мрачный, ты точно не из DC приперся?" :) `l[:]` у тебя позаимствовал - не знал, что так можно

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

inp = [
    ['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1', 'E1'],
    ['C2', 'D2', 'E2'],
    ['D3', 'E3'],
    ['A4', 'B4', 'C4', 'D4', 'E4'],
    ['C5', 'D5', 'E5'],
    ['D6', 'E6'],
    ['C7', 'D7', 'E7']
]
res = pd.DataFrame(inp).fillna(method="ffill").values.tolist()
```

тогда res будет:

```
[['A1', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1', 'E1'],
 ['C2', 'D2', 'E2', 'D1', 'E1'],
 ['D3', 'E3', 'E2', 'D1', 'E1'],
 ['A4', 'B4', 'C4', 'D4', 'E4'],
 ['C5', 'D5', 'E5', 'D4', 'E4'],
 ['D6', 'E6', 'E5', 'D4', 'E4'],
 ['C7', 'D7', 'E7', 'D4', 'E4']]
```